# My vb.net application crashes on openfileDialog using windows 10 OS

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

My vb.net application `openfileDialog` works fine on `windows 7`, but it chrashes on windows 10. I had already enabled 3.5 framework on my `windows 10` OS but still no luck.
here is my code:

```
 Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
        Try
            OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Picture Files (*)|*.bmp;*.gif;*.jpg;*.png"
            If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                OpenFileDialog1.ShowHelp = True
                pbAttachments.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

            Path_And_File_Name = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            ImgFileSize = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(Path_And_File_Name).Length

            DoubleBytes = CDbl(ImgFileSize / 1048576) 'MB
            ImgFileSize_MB = FormatNumber(DoubleBytes, 2)

            If ImgFileSize_MB > 3 Then
                MsgBox("Image attachment is limited to 3 MB, the image file size you are trying to upload is " & ImgFileSize_MB & " MB!" & vbCrLf & "Please rezize your Image!", vbExclamation)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        ReleaseMemory()
        OpenFileDialog1.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Please help, thank you!

Comment: 1) Is this a WinForms application? 2) What does `ReleaseMemory` do? 3) Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7176039/4934172).

Comment: ReleaseMemory() function is just to lessen the memory consumption of the application. i had already tried to remove it,but it doesn't fix the problem sir. :(

Comment: yes this is a Winform application.

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x614bed6f in Accounting System.exe: 0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by reinstalling windows 10 operating system then re-enabling framework 3.5