# SaveFileDialog in WPF on Windows XP shows empty file list

Tags: wpf

I'm using a Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog in a WPF application which is fine in Windows 10 but some users are still using Windows XP and initially the dialog shows no files.

Changing the file type to another type updates the list. It appears to only be the initial loading.

I've used System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog, using a "Using", making sure the Dialog has an owner Window and using BeginInvoke on the current dispatcher.

```
lSaveFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
lSaveFileDialog.Title = "Datei speichern";
lSaveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = pFilenameElements.IFilenameElement_DirectoryInfo.FullName;
lSaveFileDialog.Filter = "Word Dateien (*.doc)|*.doc|Alle Dateien (*.*)|*.*";
lSaveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
lSaveFileDialog.FileName = pSuggestedFilename;

if (lSaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        return lSaveFileDialog.FileName;
    }
```

I expect the Dialog to open and display other Word files in the current folder but it only does that if I switch the filter to "All" and then I see everything. Switching back to "Word" and I see the Word files.

On Windows 10 there is no problem.

Comment: See if this can help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176039/savefiledialog-silently-crashes-winforms-app-on-windowsxp

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've given that a try with a separate thread but alas to no avail. Event Log doesn't show anything at all either.